# Admobs overlaps fragment listview with drawer layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

I've implemented Admobs according to the [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) guide.
My app has a DrawerLayout in it's main activity layout.
The ads correctly display at the bottom of the screen for each view.

However, the list views don't resize to accommodate the ad, and so the ad obscures the list items.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268090/placing-admob-ads-below-a-listview); 
But no ads were displayed at all in any view

I tried another SO solution to change the Relative layout to a Linear layout, but that didn't work either.

Here is my activity_main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:gravity="bottom">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the code I'm using in Main to show the ads:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is an example layout file for a fragment with a listview which will go into the framelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/material_lightgreen_50" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/material_lightgreen_100"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pagetitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/material_lightgreen_500"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_stepview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/material_lightgreen_500"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/emptylist" />
```

How to make the listview tail move up so that the ad can display underneath?

Comment: You'd better post a picture of your problem.

Comment: tried adding android:scaleType="fitxy" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the relative constraint for the `FrameLayout`, you should put it above the AdView, , try this in your activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView/>
```